# Increase Speed of Image/Bitmap Display Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, garbage-collection, arrays

I've written a program that reads images in from a socket in the form of a byte[] and then tries to display them on the screen. I've followed some links I've found that say the best way to do this is to use a SurfaceView. I'm trying to allocate a byte array that will account for the biggest image I would need and then constantly use the same memory space for the new images I receive. This way the memory wouldn't have a chance to get garbage collected.

I think I have narrowed down the problem to the function call of "BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(f, 0, fileSize);". I think that this call is creating a new bitmap every time and as soon as the method returns it is being GC'ed. I attemped to use the inMutable and inBitmap field but had no luck as the size of the image changes every time. I was probably doing something wrong with it though. If anyone has any experience using that and its worked for them please let me know. Each time the byte[] size changes even by only 10 elements.

I'm trying to display the images that I am reading as fast as I can and would like to reuse the same memory space/ bitmap so that I wouldn't have to keep incurring the 30ms cost of the garbage collection. Does anyone know how I could avoid the garbage collection, or at least minimize it? The images are 640x480 and 1280x720. Below is a snippet of the code that reads in the image and displays it along with the LogCat output. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```java
static byte[] f = new byte[250000]; // allocate enough memory space for biggest image
private TutorialThread _thread;

class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    /* On start up connect socket */
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);
        if (connectSockets) {
            s2 = connect(ip, s2, port);
        }
    }
    /*
     * OnDraw - Take the byte[] and use Bitmap.decodeByteArray to decode
     * Image and then draw it on canvas
     * 
     * (Slow, Causing 30ms delay due to Garbage Collection)
     */
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap i = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(f, 0, fileSize);
        canvas.drawBitmap(i, 10, 10, null);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or
        // else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }
}

class TutorialThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Panel _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public TutorialThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c = null;
        byte[] header = new byte[16];
        while (_run) {
            Log.d("Brian", "Running");
            if (s2 != null) { // if socket isCreated
                int bytesRead = 0;
                int totalBytesRead = 0;
                fileSize = 0;

                /*
                 * read the header that contains the filesize, height, and
                 * width
                 * 
                 * don't break until we read all header values
                 */
                while (totalBytesRead != (header.length)) {
                    try {
                        bytesRead = s2.getInputStream().read(header,
                                totalBytesRead,
                                (header.length - totalBytesRead));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                    if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    } else {
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    }
                }

                // convert the filesize from bytes to int
                fileSize = (fileSize << 8) + (header[0] & 0xff);
                fileSize = (fileSize << 8) + (header[1] & 0xff);
                fileSize = (fileSize << 8) + (header[2] & 0xff);
                fileSize = (fileSize << 8) + (header[3] & 0xff);

                bytesRead = 0;

                // read the entire file. don't break until we read
                // everything
                do {
                    bytesRead = readChunk(s2, bytesRead, fileSize, f);
                } while (bytesRead != fileSize);
            } else {
                Log.d("Brian", "Socket Null");
            }
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    _panel.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

07-05 09:13:21.980: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 7040K/7431K, paused 18ms
07-05 09:13:22.010: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 7040K/7431K, paused 4ms+2ms
07-05 09:13:22.040: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_EXPLICIT freed 600K, 14% free 6440K/7431K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-05 09:13:22.060: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 6440K/7431K, paused 19ms
07-05 09:13:22.060: I/dalvikvm-heap(25075): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.994MB for 614416-byte allocation
07-05 09:13:22.080: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 7040K/7431K, paused 21ms
07-05 09:13:22.120: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 7040K/7431K, paused 3ms+2ms
07-05 09:13:22.150: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_EXPLICIT freed 600K, 14% free 6440K/7431K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-05 09:13:22.170: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 6440K/7431K, paused 19ms
07-05 09:13:22.170: I/dalvikvm-heap(25075): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.994MB for 614416-byte allocation
07-05 09:13:22.190: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 7040K/7431K, paused 19ms
07-05 09:13:22.220: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 7040K/7431K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-05 09:13:22.250: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_EXPLICIT freed 600K, 14% free 6440K/7431K, paused 2ms+1ms
07-05 09:13:22.270: D/dalvikvm(25075): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 6440K/7431K, paused 18ms
07-05 09:13:22.270: I/dalvikvm-heap(25075): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.994MB for 614416-byte allocation
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and you already mentioned the solution:

```
opts.inBitmap
```

As you said, the new Bitmap must have the same size as the previous one.
Additionally you have to set

```
opts.inSampleSize = 1;
```

Example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 1;

while (...) {
    // first call will create a new bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
    // subsequent calls will re-use the first bitmap
    opt.inBitmap = bitmap;
    // check (dump bitmaps memory address, should always output the same string)
    Log.d("bitmapID", bitmap.toString());
}
```

In my case, this totally removed the GCs needed for the Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that this call is creating a new bitmap every time and as soon
>   as the method returns it is being GC'ed.

That is precisely what's happening.  It's creating a new bitmap from your buffer every call.  The old one is thrown away regardless if it's the same bitmap.  Do not ever create objects in the "onDraw" method of a view, especially bitmaps.  This method could potentially be called hundreds of times in the view's existence and creating objects is costly.

The best option would be to wait until the buffer is filled with a new bitmap, then call `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(f, 0, fileSize);`  Keeping the reference to the bitmap within the scope of the class.  Also remember to call `recycle()` on the old bitmap just before creating the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've moved the decodeByteArray out of the onDraw function but am still having the same issue. Essentially that is what I am doing. I am waiting for the entire buffer to be read from the socket and then I would call the onDraw function which was doing the decoding and drawing. I moved the decoding to the TutorialThread  inner class right above the try for the surfaceholder and same luck. I think that the problem is anywhere I call that decodeByteArray function it will always incur the garbage collection. Any idea on how to work around that function call? thanks.

Comment: If you must create a new bitmap when you get a new one, then no. You pretty much have to use BitmapFactory to decode the bit array. The garbage collection occurs when the old bitmap is thrown away (and there's possibly some cleanup that occurs in the function itself).

You may be able to mitigate the effect by putting the old bitmap in a soft reference.  It'll cache it until the memory is needed then will get thrown away.